# Special Characters in JSON return value throwing errors

Tags: javascript, json

I have some code using datatables and one of the fields that is returned is a string value and lately people have been pasting values in this field from emails that contain some special characters like those found in MS-Word smart quotes.  When it tries to display I get an error.

If I copy / paste the text into notepad++ I can see some strange symbols.  Once I remove them the error goes away.

Is there away to some how strip all special characters from my text with a function call in Javascript?

Comment: JSON can hold Unicode characters, you shouldn't need to do anything special. How are you encoding the JSON?

Comment: I'm just fetching the values from a REST service.  The text contained characters that showed up as symbols in notepad++ .  After I removed them the json displayed fine.  I believe I have the answer shown below where I strip out everything except letters, numbers and spaces.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34649086/2238515

Comment: How are you displaying them? If you're getting an error, the problem is there; removing all punctuation characters seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify()` at all?

Comment: @DanielD I think he's **receiving** JSON, not generating it.

Comment: Can U give an exmple of the "bad" JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this woks for you:

```
myStr=myStr.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

You can add more characters to this "white list" for example:

```
myStr=myStr.replace(/[^\w\s,\/#!$%\^&\*;:]/gi, '');
```

Comment: Close enough.  I just found [^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g

Comment: This will also remove ordinary punctuation characters.

Comment: @Barmar true, you can add to this "white list" more characters

Comment: It just seems like he's solving the wrong problem. He should fix the display code so it can display anything.

Comment: @Barmar agree again, however this is what he wanted. we need some code to solve the display