# Stop JSON.stringify from adding escape characters

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object,

```
var obj = {};
```

Where I set a property

```
obj['prop'] = 'This is a "property"'
```

How can I stop

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

from returning

```
"This is a \"property\""
```

and instead return

```
"This is a "property""
```

Ideally, is there a way to do this where I set the property? i.e.

```
obj['prop'] = 'This is a "property"'
```

Comment: well, why is there such a requirement, if I may?

Comment: So, you don't want valid JSON after all? Then don't use a JSON serialiser.

Comment: The JSON spec reserves `"` for defining keys and values. A valid JSON will escape `"` characters in the value.

Comment: ... that's how it works. Javascript allows you to create strings with `'` and `"` but they eventually lead to the same result (depending of the content between those quotes ofc). The double quote is always being escaped here.

Comment: @kukkuz Well, I'm not the one who chose to build the code this way. It's what I have to work with. The goal is to programmatically produce a file that's used by a software that requires this format

Comment: Which, quite frankly, is nuts, since I have no idea how that software reliably disambiguates where the string `"a "property""` begins and ends… my condolences.

Comment: JSON.stringify takes a second parameter of a repeater. See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649086/3239219

Comment: @KarelG Javascript allows you to create strings with `'`, `"` and `\``! `\`` allows for multiline strings in your code, and allows you to use `'` and `"` together.

Comment: @deceze it's an odd task, but the end software is Terraform, which requires double quotes be unescaped in its functions

Comment: "it's functions"…? Soo… is Terraform parsing *JSON*, or are you trying to code-generate here…?

Comment: @deceze Code generate. Terraform doesn't parse JSON, but we've had no issues up until now with this new parameter

Comment: Then you're not really generating *JSON* to begin with…? Also: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html#json-syntax

Comment: @deceze We're trying to keep the Terraform syntax, so unfortunately pure JSON won work. I think the goal wasn't to generate JSON, but this is just a byproduct of the code was designed to store information about variables

Comment: In that case, store the information in a way that works for you. For instance, CSV with a custom delimiter?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want this, you might use something like `JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\/g,'')`.

**Beware**: the output will NOT be a valid JSON, and dataloss can occur if you have any 'legit' backslashes in your JSON.

Comment: Of course, this would also remove all "legit" backslashes you may actually *want* from your data…

Comment: Yes, I'm worried about that too, so I probably won't end going this route

Comment: @db2791 if you can explain *why* you want this, we might be able to help you better...

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans It's the code I have to work with. The end file is used by Terraform, which requires that any double quotes that are used in functions be kept without escape characters. The goal is to programmatically generate those functions

Comment: But, are the functions themselves defined in a JSON, or is there another program that will get the JSON and put it into Terraform? Because that way you could remove the escape characters before it's fed to Terraform.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans They aren't defined in JSON, but so far there have been no issues with the properties we've had to set. Now there is a new one that requires double quotes, so this issue arises. I will look for a program that can do it, but I seriously doubt there is one.

Comment: @db2791 if you're still working on this, I advise you to just use Terraform JSONS. Terraform can work with JSONs directly, while a bit more difficult to read, it works almost exactly the same as HCL files.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, you cannot prevent that a double quote (`"`) is being escaped because that character is reserved (defined in specs). What you can do is do use a work-around: use a single quote `'` to quote something in a text.

If you still want to see a double quote here-after, then it's something difficult to achieve. Replacing the `'` into `"` is not enough because there are words that use `'` naturally. Like `it's` or `don't`

```js
const obj = {};

obj['myKey'] = "first word is 'Hello World'";
obj['anotherKey'] = "second word is 'Lorum Ispum'...";

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```