# Converting Object into JSON and downloading as a .json file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a javascript object that contains some information.
I want to convert this into JSON and download it as a .json file.
Seems like I can just to `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert it into JSON
but how do I actually download it as a .json file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a React-specific issue if you're just looking to download data via JavaScript, but here's a snippet I use that creates a link to download the data content, virtually clicking the element, and finally removing it from the DOM.  It should support both modern browsers and older IEs:

```
private exportToJson(objectData: SomeObject) {
    let filename = "export.json";
    let contentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8;";
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(JSON.stringify(objectData)))], { type: contentType });
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = 'data:' + contentType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(objectData));
      a.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  }
```

It's also worth noting that there are a number of ways to approach this as cited [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery).

Comment: This stores json data as "{\"name\":\"cliff\",\"age\":\"34\"}" f.e.
Is there a way to prettify it so that the escape characters are removed and every value is on a new line?

Comment: Interestingly, I'm not able to replicate the escape character issue, but for pretty-print, you can use the 3rd argument for `JSON.stringify` so something like `JSON.stringify(objectData, null, 2)` which will include `LF` characters for pretty-printing and 2 spaces per level of depth in the object being stringified.

Comment: I'll add separately that the 2nd argument of `JSON.stringify` is a replacer which can be a function that modifies keys and values in the object.  I imagine you could use a function similar to the one provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649086) to remedy extraneous characters being printed

Answer (score 11):

For those arriving here and searching for an easier solution:

```
         <a
            href={`data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
              JSON.stringify(YOURJSON)
            )}`}
            download="filename.json"
          >
            {`Download Json`}
          </a>
```

Comment: Using JSON.stringify(YOURJSON, null, '\t') instead will also download the json formatted. I've proposed the change.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to create a file directly on your computer's file system as this would be a huge security risk. You cannot do this from a web page using JavaScript.

You could write a server side service to post your state to and it creates a file - you may then download the file or be content with where your server side stores it.

Another way via inMemory [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)