# How to print JSON as string without getting extra backslash characters?

Tags: javascript, json

This code:

```
req.reject({
    name: 'Server returned error',
    message: (`${message.errorcode}${message.data ? `, data: ${JSON.stringify(message.data)}` : ''}`)
});
```

produces output with unwanted `\` characters:

```
{ 
    name: 'Server returned error',
    message: 'Command failure, data: {"message":"No device with name \'aAASDASDA\' connected."}' 
}
```

This code:

```
req.reject({
    name: 'Server returned error',
    message: (`${message.errorcode}${message.data ? `, data: ${message.data}` : ''}`)
});
```

produces output with keys and values hidden

```
{ 
    name: 'Server returned error',
    message: 'Command failure, data: [object Object]' 
}
```

How can I produce output with keys and values but no extra `\` characters

```
{ 
    name: 'Server returned error',
    message: 'Command failure, data: {"message":"No device with name 'aAASDASDA' connected."}' 
}
```

Comment: There is no extra `\\`, that's just how JSON does escaping.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648904/how-can-i-remove-escape-sequences-from-json-stringify-so-that-its-human-readabl?rq=1

Comment: The posted code doesn´t produce any output...

Comment: `JSON.stringify` definitely doesn't do that: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/n4tc2frm/. *"produces output with unwanted \ characters"* What are you using to output/view it? The single quotes around it suggest you're using something that shows you strings wrapped in single quotes (and so of course escapes single quotes within the string), but if so the string won't actually have backslashes in it. It's just rendered that way.

Comment: This might also help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Comment: To give you something to think about, what do you think the result of this is -> `console.log(JSON.parse("\"\\\"hello\\\"\""))`