# Format json output programatically in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I format the json output file to format the content like in the example?

```
[
  {"keyA1": "value1", "keyA2": "value2", "KeyAN": "valueN"},
  {"keyB1": "value1", "keyB2": "value2", "KeyBN": "valueN"},
  {"keyC1": "value1", "keyC2": "value2", "KeyCN": "valueN"},
]
```

There are a ton of answers like this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614874) but this is not how I want it.

EDIT: maybe the question is not clear to everyone. I want the json file to be formated like this, not the javascript.

EDIT 2: this is how I am doing it now:

```
    const newAdmin = { 
        id: Math.floor(dateNow.getTime() / 1000), 
        firstName: firstName, 
        lastName: lastName, 
        birthDate: new Date(birthDate).toLocaleDateString(),
        registrationDay: dateNow.toLocaleDateString()
    };
    members.push(newAdmin);

    await Deno.writeFile(membersFilePath!, encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(members, null, 1)));
```

Comment: Where are you outputting it to? The console or a text file?

Comment: to a text file, more specific to a json

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the added benefit of formatting your JSON this way? Do you need it to be human readable? If so, have you considered reading the JSON and presenting it in a readable fashion with the browser?

Comment: just personal preference

Answer (score 2):

You can try mapping through each item individually and stringifying, then joining together by a linebreak:

```js
var arr = [{"keyA1": "value1", "keyA2": "value2", "KeyAN": "valueN"},{"keyB1": "value1", "keyB2": "value2", "KeyBN": "valueN"},{"keyC1": "value1", "keyC2": "value2", "KeyCN": "valueN"},]

const result = "[\n" + arr.map(e => '  ' + JSON.stringify(e)).join(',\n') + "\n]";

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but this is the output in the json file:
"[\n  {\"id\":1670713260,\"user\":\"new user\",\"city\":\"berlin\",\"registrationDay\":\"12/11/2022\"}\n]"

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648904/how-can-i-remove-escape-sequences-from-json-stringify-so-that-its-human-readabl

Answer (score -1):

How about a manual way of doing it. Check the code below:

```js
const data = [{"keyA1": "value1", "keyA2": "value2", "KeyAN": "valueN"},{"keyB1": "value1", "keyB2": "value2", "KeyBN": "valueN"},{"keyC1": "value1", "keyC2": "value2", "KeyCN": "valueN"},];

        let json = "[";

        for (const item of data) {
            json += "\n  {";

            for (const key in item) {
                json += `"${key}": "${item[key]}",`;
            }

            json += "},";
        }

        json += "\n]";

        console.log(json);
```

Comment: This is not OP was asking for, Please re-read the question.

Comment: Edited the question to make the answer output exactly as the OP requested.

Comment: @Tinaria, check out this answer.

Comment: the json file is not coming out in the right format. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I read the json file, push a new object into it. and that new array I am trying to write. but the format is not as desired

Comment: How are you outputting to the file, share your code.

Comment: I will edit my question and write it there